# What does SetApplicationName actually do in reference to AddDataProtection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Consider [this example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#setapplicationname):

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("TestingApp");
```

The docs seem to indicate that setting the application name like this will allow two servers to know that they should use the same key for cookies (assuming that [it is also persisted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) using something like `PersistKeysToDbContext`).

However, when I look at the persisted key, I don't see the shared application name anywhere in the document:

```
<key id="c34df9c6-bf38-49e8-97cf-dda5f8bc141c" version="1">
  <creationDate>2021-03-23T21:47:20.4615267Z</creationDate>
  <activationDate>2021-03-23T21:47:19.4492298Z</activationDate>
  <expirationDate>2021-06-21T21:47:19.4492298Z</expirationDate>
  <descriptor deserializerType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=3.1.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60">
    <descriptor>
      <encryption algorithm="AES_256_CBC" />
      <validation algorithm="HMACSHA256" />
      <masterKey xmlns:p4="http://schemas.asp.net/2015/03/dataProtection" p4:requiresEncryption="true">
        <!-- Warning: the key below is in an unencrypted form. -->
        <value>eNZoh1a2DEiEi03ae1aklP9dM3z____FAKE_____Pgy8bcVpkOI+q/I9d9iELvy+ptOW54Q==</value>
      </masterKey>
    </descriptor>
  </descriptor>
</key>
```

The "Friendly Name" of the key seems to be a Guid.

**What does SetApplication actually cause to change in the persisted xml?**

Comment: Not sure if going straight to the source might help https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/DataProtectionBuilderExtensions.cs,f42f99201351fd19

Comment: Found where it is used in anti forgery https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/Internal/AntiforgeryOptionsSetup.cs,17

Comment: Add data protection uses the name to create (deferred) the protector https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/DataProtectionServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,100

Answer (score 1):

*SetApplicationName* does not cause any change in persisted xml. In fact, you can change the Application name at any time after the XML is generated.

Application name is used as a master Purpose string for *IDataProtectionProvider*.

Consider the following code example:

```
// Startup.cs
services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName( "My application name" );

// ExampleConsumer.cs
public ExampleConsumer( IDataProtectionProvider protectionProvider )
{
    var dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector( "My protector" );
}
```

If you run this code in a debugger and check the purposes, it will look like this:

```
protectionProvider.Purposes: ["My application name"]  
dataProtector.Purposes: ["My application name", "My protector"]
```

---

For more information on purposes, see [Purpose hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/purpose-strings-multitenancy?view=aspnetcore-6.0).